# PHP On scope resolution operator

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    class a {   

     function fn () {
            echo "My name here";
        }

    }   

a::fn();     
?>
```

I used scope resolution operator to check how it works, it gave no error when i checked in browser it printed correctly.

But same code when I run nusphere PhpEd debugger tool it gave me error like

Strict Standards: Non-static method a::fn() should not be called statically in D:\Program_Files\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 12
My name here

but it printed the results correctly. May i know what actuall problem is , I am new to PHP classes.I tried in google but i didn't get the reason.

Advance Thanks

Comment: do you need to call it as a static menthod?  why not try:  

$a = new a();
$->fn();

Comment: Different settings of error reporting can create the difference you experience.

Answer (score 3):

The error you're seeing is `E_STRICT`, which may not be displayed on your server. If you set `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)` you'll probably see that error.

The reason you're seeing the error is that the function `fn` is not declared static, so you can't necessarily call it statically (like `a::fn()`). You would call a non-static method like this:

```
$a = new a();
$a->fn();
```

To make your function static, change the method declaration:

```
public static function fn() {
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT**: [This manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.this) shows an example similar to yours above.

Answer (score 1):

do you need to call it as a static menthod?  why not try:

```
$a = new a();
$a->fn();
```

this should work ^^